# iPhone - Saving and Loading a user's login information from file

Tags: ios, keychain, nsfilemanager

Hey guys, I am having a bit of a problem trying to save a user's Login (email) and password (chars/nums). These are both UITextFields of NSStrings.

I have it set up right now at the end of the view before it gets dismissed as

```
[email writeToFile:@"Login" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
[password writeToFile:@"Password" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

However, I am not sure as how to go about loading these when the view is loaded.
I tried doing this at the beginning of the view loading:

```
NSString *email;
NSString *password;
NSError *error;
NSString *em = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"Login" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]; 
NSString *pass = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"Password" encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (error == nil) {
   userEmail.text = em;
   userPassword.text = pass; 
}

email = userEmail.text;
password = userPassword.text;
```

However, I cannot actually get the data in these two files..is it because I have to have the full path to the file? Also, is there a way to save these both into one file (NSMutableDictionary)? Any advice would be great!!

Alex

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should not store a user's credentials in plain text in a file.  It can easily be read if the phone is ever lost or hacked.

A much better approach is to store the information securely in the iPhone Keychain.  This will handle the encryption/decryption for you, and is more secure than what you're likely to write yourself.

One library that will make working with the Keychain easier is [SFHFKeychainUtils](https://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone).  This will give you an abstraction that works on the Simulator as well as the device.

Comment: I will have to look into this and see which is really the best choice to go with.

Comment: It may not be the prettiest choice, but it is the Apple recommendation for this sort of storage.

Comment: Will it get rejected from the app store if this method is not used?

Comment: No, just recommendation, not requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at NSUserDefaults instead, but to answer your question you might want to specify the path.

Get Path:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *docDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Login", docDir];
```

Save:

```
[em writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Load:

```
NSString *em = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
```

Don't forget to [em release] to avoid memory leaks!

Comment: But as Ben Scheirman said, it's much much better to store user login in the keychain.